# How can I pass a variable for a jinja macro from the controller?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

In a controller (//view) I perform an `exists` operation on the database.
If the result is positive, I return the same URL and the form and flash a message.

When doing this, I'd like to render one of the fields (ie. form.email) with an extra variable set (that normally defaults to None) in order mark it as an erring field.

How can I do this using jinja templates and flask?

I am not asking for code but direction as I am unable to figure out the way to go.

I am working with Flask, WTForms and Jinja.

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of ways to pass data around when working with jinja, but without seeing some code, we can't really help point you toward what you need to change to pass some new data.

Comment: Hi @IfLoop, I solved the issue using WTForms' field.flags helper class. I will delete the question in a minute. Thank you for your kind interest in helping.

Comment: @Phil Don't delete it, post an answer to your own question and accept it - that's totally fine on SO, and is even encouraged.

Comment: @LukasGraf, thank you for letting me know and encouraging. I have posted a response. I shall accept it as the correct one in two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your procedure encounters a (high level) operational error and you can not declare this as a `validator` within your `WTForm` objects, you might want to find another solution to mark that specific `field` as erring.

One way to do this can be using `WTForms`' helper class `flags`.

Ex:

```
form.field_name.flags.erring = True
```

Then when you are rendering your field, via a macro or not, you can check to see if `erring` flag is set to `True`.